# Converting to mapping-by-code causes major performance issues

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I have an NHibernate project which uses mapping config files. I'm using an SQL Server database.

I want to switch to mapping by code. My approach is to do this one class at a time, confirming that all of the tests pass with each changeover.

Mixing the two mappings is quite straighforward:

```
  public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
  {
     get
     {
        if (_sessionFactory == null)
        {
           var configuration = new Configuration();

           configuration.Configure();
           configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Entities.Player).Assembly);



           var mapper = new NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.ModelMapper();
           // Here are the entities I've switched to mapping-by-code
           DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Mappings.ScheduleMediaItem.Map(mapper);
           DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Mappings.Schedule.Map(mapper);

           configuration.AddMapping(mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities());
           _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
        }
        return _sessionFactory;
     }
  }
```

However, when I changed over the `Schedule` mapping to being mapping-by-code, I encountered major performance issues. Calls to `Session.Flush` would take 12 seconds, and this is over a trivial amount of test data.

I switched back to the XML mapping, and the performance problems went away.

Has anyone else experienced the problem?

I'll include the before and after mappings for `schedule`, just in case there's an obvious defect:

Via the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
   <class name="DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Entities.Schedule, DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary" table="cms_Schedule">
      <id name="Id" column="Id" type="Int64">
         <generator class="identity" />
      </id>
      <property name="Date" column="Date" type="Timestamp" />
      <many-to-one name="SourceTemplate" column="SourceTemplate_Id" class="DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Entities.ScheduleTemplate, DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary" cascade="none" fetch="join" lazy="proxy"/>
     <!-- 
      Note that we are not using cascading deletes here.
      This will be handled by SQL Server through ON DELETE CASCADE foreign key constraints     
     -->
      <bag name="MediaItems" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" lazy="true" order-by="PlayIndex">
         <key column="Schedule_Id" />
         <one-to-many class="DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Entities.ScheduleMediaItem, DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary"/>
      </bag>
     <bag name="PlayerGroups" table="cms_ManyToMany_PlayerGroupSchedules_PlayerGroup_Schedule" lazy="true" cascade="save-update">
       <key column="Schedule_Id" />
       <many-to-many column="PlayerGroup_Id"
                     class="DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Entities.PlayerGroup, NHibernateManyToMany" />
     </bag>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the mapping by code:

```
    public static void Map(ModelMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.Class<DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Entities.Schedule>(
            classMapper =>
            {
                classMapper.Table("cms_Schedule");
                classMapper.Id(x => x.Id, map =>
                    {
                        map.Column("Id");
                        map.Generator(Generators.Identity);
                    });
                classMapper.Property(
                        s => s.Date,
                        propertyMapper =>
                        {
                            propertyMapper.Column("Date");
                            propertyMapper.NotNullable(true);
                        }
                );
                classMapper.ManyToOne(
                                s => s.SourceTemplate,
                                manyToOneMapper =>
                                {
                                    manyToOneMapper.Column("SourceTemplate_Id");
                                    manyToOneMapper.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                                    manyToOneMapper.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
                                    manyToOneMapper.Lazy(LazyRelation.Proxy);
                                }
                );
                classMapper.Bag(
                            s => s.MediaItems,
                            bagPropertyMapper =>
                            {
                                bagPropertyMapper.Key(keyMapper =>
                                                    {
                                                        keyMapper.Column("Schedule_Id");

                                                    }
                                );
                                bagPropertyMapper.Inverse(true);
                                bagPropertyMapper.Cascade(Cascade.Persist);
                                bagPropertyMapper.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Lazy);
                                bagPropertyMapper.OrderBy(smi => smi.PlayIndex);
                            }
                );
                classMapper.Bag(
                        s => s.PlayerGroups,
                        bagPropertyMapper =>
                        {
                            bagPropertyMapper.Key(keyMapper =>
                                {
                                    keyMapper.Column("Schedule_Id");
                                });

                            bagPropertyMapper.Table("cms_ManyToMany_PlayerGroupSchedules_PlayerGroup_Schedule");
                            bagPropertyMapper.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Extra);
                            bagPropertyMapper.Cascade(Cascade.Persist);
                        },
                        collectionElementRelation =>
                            {
                                collectionElementRelation.ManyToMany(manyToManyMapper =>
                                    {
                                        manyToManyMapper.Column("PlayerGroup_Id");
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                    );
            }

            );
    }
```

---

**Later edit**

I made the problem go away by not calling `Flush` within a transaction.

I've tried to create some simpler test code to replicate the problem, but have been unsuccessful (all my test code runs really fast, no matter how many times I call Flush). This could be because I converted some entitys' key generation from `Identity` to `HiLo`.

So it seems in my case, my code was creating a particular configuration which brought about a problem, and hopefully this won't come back to haunt me.

If I guessed, I would say the configuration that causes problems involves a combination of  thoughtless use of long running transactions combined with Identity key generation.

Answer (score 2):

I have used mixed mappings in quite a few projects and have not experienced any problems as you describe. I cannot see why the flush would take 12 seconds.

My technique for mixed mappings is slightly different to yours and I am not 100% sure if the `order` you configure matters, its worth a shot. See http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/mixed-mappings-with-hbm-and-mapping-by.html

I take it you have you exported ALL the mappings and double checked that they **ARE** the same before and after. See http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/view-xml-generated-when-mapping-by-code.html